# Keep deb updated using repository

Tags: apt, repository, deb, debian

I'm using [Materia GTK theme](https://github.com/nana-4/materia-theme) in ubuntu 18.04. It's in the repos but it's an older version. I'm trying to keep it updated (when I update my system, just like Spotify .deb does). So I've tried to use the https://packages.debian.org/unstable/materia-gtk-theme repository in Software and sources GUI , adding `deb https://packages.debian.org/ sid all materia-gtk-theme, but I've got the following error.

```
E: GPG error: https://packages.debian.org unstable Release: Signed file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?). "
```

Anyone knows how fix it? Or use another way to keep my theme always updated? (Currently there is no official PPA.)

Comment: The current version of `materia-gtk-theme`, 20180928-1, is in Ubuntu 18.10. Upgrading from 18.04 to 18.10 will fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, I know that is in Ubuntu 18.10... But this is my main machine, production wise. I was not planing to upgrade. Is there any way I can use the materia-gtk-theme from ubuntu 18.10 repos in 18.04 and keep it updated?

Comment: You can download it from http://packages.ubuntu.com. Warning: It's not tested on 18.04 and it's not supported in 18.04 (unwise for a production system). If it breaks your system, you're on your own. Ubuntu uses a snapshot method of upgrading - the package gets upgraded once every 6 months as part of preparing the next release of Ubuntu...there seems little point adding a repo for one package every six months.

Comment: I see. well , I've installed it manually and works just fine. I think I'm going to keep it updated manually from time to time (removing and reinstalling) . Thanks for the help